# Copy data validations only from a single row from one table to all rows of another table

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to copy only the data validations from a table called **Table1_1** on the worksheet **TEMPLATE (Maint.)** to a table on another worksheet called **TEMPLATE**. I have looked at the available topic but none come quite close to what I am looking for.

One of the problems are the table on either of these sheets may end up shifting so when I build this macro I will need to take that into account.

So far what I have is:

1. Copy the first (and only row) of **Table1_1** on worksheet **TEMPLATE (Maint.)**.
2. Look at cell A3 on worksheet **TEMPLATE** and get the table it belongs to.
3. Find the first row of the table found in step 2.
4. Paste data validations of all columns in the table on the first row.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for all rows of the table.

The code I have so far:

```
Dim TotalSheets As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult

' This Dim is supposed to be to add worksheets, for the process _
' of copying the data validations to the new sheets, to a skip _
' list. An array perhaps? Skip any sheets listed in this array?
Dim DNCToShts As ?

' The cell to get the table that it is apart of for copying from _
' the other worksheet, "TEMPLATE (Maint.)"
Dim GetCellsTable_Copy As String
' The cell to get the table that it is apart of for pasting onto _
' the other worksheets.
Dim GetCellsTable_Paste As String

' This is the cell to reference on "TEMPLATE (Maint.)" worksheet _
' to get the table name of, this will always be "Table1_1"
GetCellsTable_Copy = "A3"
' This is the cell to reference on each sheet to get the table name.
GetCellsTable_Paste = "A3"

With Aplication
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

iAnswer = MsgBox("You are about to copy data validations! Do you _
want to proceed?", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation _
+ vbDefaultButton2 + vbMsgBoxSetForeground + vbApplicationModal, _
"Copying Data Valadations")

' Instead of copying the whole table I just need to copy the first row _
' of data, intending to copy just the data validations portion.
Range("Table1_1").Copy

If iAnswer = vbYes Then
    p = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If UCase$(Sheets(p).Name) <> DNCToShts
        StoreTableName = Range(GetCellsTable_Paste).ListObject.Name
```

I have created a diagram showing what I am aiming to accomplish with each of my Excel VBA modules. Keep in mind this may not include all details and I am working on **Part 1 only**.:
[image: Diagram showing the sequence of sub usage]

Comment: Please post some or all of your code for reference

Comment: @TheGuyThatDoesntKnowMuch I have added the code I have already accumulated. Is there anything you can gather or does something need further explaining?

Comment: I basically don't have much code written other than what is pasted in above. :-/

Answer (score 1):

The Excel VBA online help has everything needed for you to have done this. Just the help page for Validation object members should be sufficient.

The following routine will copy a validation from one cell to another. You should be able to call it in a double-loop (for target rows and columns). Once you're done testing it out, this should probably be a `Private` function

```
Sub CopyValidation(ByRef rngSourceCell As Range, ByRef rngTargetCell As Range)
    With rngTargetCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=rngSourceCell.Validation.Type, _
            AlertStyle:=rngSourceCell.Validation.AlertStyle, _
            Operator:=rngSourceCell.Validation.Operator, Formula1:=rngSourceCell.Validation.Formula1, Formula2:=rngSourceCell.Validation.Formula2
        .ErrorMessage = rngSourceCell.Validation.ErrorMessage
        .ErrorTitle = rngSourceCell.Validation.ErrorTitle
        .IgnoreBlank = rngSourceCell.Validation.IgnoreBlank
        .IMEMode = rngSourceCell.Validation.IMEMode
        .InCellDropdown = rngSourceCell.Validation.InCellDropdown
        .InputMessage = rngSourceCell.Validation.InputMessage
        .InputTitle = rngSourceCell.Validation.InputTitle
        .ShowError = rngSourceCell.Validation.ShowError
        .ShowInput = rngSourceCell.Validation.ShowInput
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me see if I can get this integrated into my code some how, this does look promising. FYI yes, I am running this as it's own Sub (Sub Copy_Data_Validations()).

Comment: Did you mean to state "...this should probably be it's own Private function." instead of "...a Private function"?

Comment: I should have said "private sub". "Function" was wrong word to use. It is already written as a Sub. What I meant was that you could use it as it is to test it using the Debug Window. Once you're OK with it, you could add the Private qualifier in front of it. Not a big deal, either way. (I have a tendency to make everything Private by default and only explicitly make things Public that I need to be public. )

Comment: Ok MikeC, not a problem. Does this only copy and paste one cell at a time? Can a range of cells be pasted at once? I would need the method that would work best with copying a row of validations from the maintenance tab to a single table, for every row, on each tab minus select worksheets.

Comment: This copies data validation from one cell to another. This allows you to put it in loops copying validations from whatever source cells you want to whatever target cells (one source to many targets for example). This allows for different source cells with different validations to be copied to different number of target cells. Just call it repeatedly as you need in loops.

Comment: *nods* good, this seems like it'll work but it may take me a bit just to get it implemented, I'm very burnt out on programming at this point :/
Should I just mark it as the answer now or when I've finally made it work do you think?

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure how to initiate IM on this site, or I'd have responded using that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107625/discussion-between-david-s-and-mikec).